# helping in finding out the concept of a sentence

Tags: meaning

**Trash art has been around for years, and it seems to make a comeback from time to time.** But it seems that only the more eccentric or popular artists are viewed as true artists when working with items normally discarded in the trash pile. Why can’t average people be considered artists when they pull the same items out and mold them into some form of personal art of their own creating? Maybe it’s because we all have our own pre-set ideas of what art is and isn’t, or who artists are or should be.

I am wondering if it has been around or there has been such art how it is coming?-- I mean it had been around.

Could you through an example show me the concept or the relationship between the bold part sentences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been around = has existed

makes a comeback = has renewed popularity

The implicit idea is that the  art form's popularity wanes, and then experiences a resurgence. This has happened at various times. It may not be periodic or cyclical, but it's something we can expect to happen "from time to time".